# Error adding LSTM layers to model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, mnist

So I am trying to build a model using some LSTM layers together with some Convolution ones. I'm using fashion Mnist dataset. The first convolution is okay, but as soon as I add the LSTM layers I get an error. Besides, if I only add one LSTM layer together with the FC everything goes okay. I can't even add new layers, cause I want to improve the model too. Help is much appreciated.

My data:

```
img_rows = 28
img_cols = 28
batch_size = 512
img_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], *img_shape)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], *img_shape)
x_val = x_val.reshape(x_val.shape[0], *img_shape)

label_as_binary = LabelBinarizer()
y_train_binary = label_as_binary.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test_binary = label_as_binary.fit_transform(y_test)
y_val_binary = label_as_binary.fit_transform(y_val)
```

My model:

```
model4 = Sequential([
  Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
  input_shape=img_shape),
  LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
  LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),

  Dropout(0.25),
  Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  ]) 

model4.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop'), 
   metrics=['accuracy'])

model4.fit(
   x_train,
   y_train_binary,
   batch_size=batch_size,
   epochs=10,
   verbose=1,
   validation_data=(x_val, y_val_binary)
)
```

The error in the model:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 26, 26, 32)

Comment: Why are you using an lstm for this? The data isn’t sequential

Comment: you are right, I have to do 4 different models for an assignment and I wanted to do a different one with LSTMs, but you are right, I'll get rid of the LSTMs and stick with convolutions, thanks.